# In Python how do you ask the user to put in a character instead of a number

Tags: python-3.x, loops, input

I'm creating a simple interactive story game where I ask the user to input and display to them some sentences. what I want to do is ask the user where they're from and if they enter an int instead of a string. I would like to repeatedly ask where they're from without the user inputting an int. I've tried if and while loops and it seems not to work for me

```
import time

name = input("what is your name? ")

def greeting (name):
    print("hhhmmm..... is that so?")
    time.sleep(0)
    x = input("Well " + name + " where have you been all these years?")
    place_char = ""
    while True:
        if x == place_char:
            break
            # I want to keep asking for location until the user put a string or char not a number
        print("please enter a location ")
    print("So " + name + " you're telling me that you've been at " + x + " this entir time?")

greeting(name)
```

Comment: There are lots of possibilities, few that come to my mind are you can either do a `regex` check if there are digits in user input or make a really long `if` statement like `if "1" in x or "2" in x` etc

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `isalpha()` to return `True` if all characters in the alphabet:

```
x.isalpha()
```

If this returns `False`, ask for a new input and continue the while loop.

```
while x.isalpha() == False:
    x = input("please enter a location ")
```

Comment: FWIW: It is better to use `is` instead of `==` for boolean values, or you can even better use `while not x.isalpha():` here.